# NodeJS Object Require

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Scenario: You login to your account, and a Player object is populated with your data from the db. This object has methods that will update the DB.

Issue: what's the best way to define such an object? How do I define it so that node can use these methods at will? Do I need to pass the `Player` object as a parameter or do I have to re-require it (will that re-define the object?) Will the `req` parameter "expire" or have the wrong scope?

```
module.exports = {
    createPlayer:Player
}

function Player(id,con,mysql,req) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x;
    this.y;
    this.con = con;
    this.mysql = mysql;
    this.req = req;
}

Player.prototype = {
    move:function() {

    }
}
```

And lastly, how do `require` it and initialize it with node?

```
var player = (new require("Player")); //this is a guess to be honest
```

Comment: Why are you creating the `Player` in a separate module?

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't want to clutter my `server.js` file

Comment: So, your question is, how to create objects with this function required from other module?

Comment: Right, this object might have extensive prototype methods, so I want it to have its own file, but the same functionality as if I defined it inside the server file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**player.js**

```
function Player(id,con,mysql,req) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x;
    this.y;
    this.con = con;
    this.mysql = mysql;
    this.req = req;
}

Player.prototype = {
    move:function() {

    }
}

module.exports = Player;
```

Use it in another file now

```
var Player = require("./player");

// create player instance
var p = new Player(id,con,mysql,req);
```

Comment: Could you address the smaller questions as well? Will the `request` param need to be updated whenever I call a method? Will I have to send as a param to other functions or can I make it a global object?

Answer (score 1):

Node uses [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) for its module pattern system. There is nothing inherently magical about the way these objects are called by node. It is "lazy" in a sense that a new module isn't initialized until the first require call.  After, the object is cached for duration of execution by default.

If I understand what you're trying to do I would rewrite your example as such:

```
// player.js
function Player(id,con,mysql,req) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x;
    this.y;
    this.con = con;
    this.mysql = mysql;
    this.req = req;
}

Player.prototype.move = function() {
    // logic
}

module.exports = function() {
     return new Player(arguments);
}
```

In your server file:

```
var player = require('./player');

app.post('/player', function(req, res, next) {
    res.player = player(req.id, con, mysql, req);
    // at this point res.player is an instance of the object you wrote, with
    // everything populated, based on request
    // be careful as all objects are passed by reference, so if say mysql is your
    // mysql client, it can mutate and change unexpectedly.
});
```

Comment: I'm thinking hoisting this object to the global level would be appropriate to avoid these mutations?

Comment: typically, pollution of `global` isn't the `node` way, the way people solve it is by doing `var mysql = require('mysql'); mysql.client = mysql.connect();` then elsewhere, `var mysql = require('mysql');` will have the correct client object. I usually wrap that kind of code into my own "db connection init" module. Happy to provide link to an example